# IntelliJ Smart Line Join works with Java but not with Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an IntelliJ project with both Java and Scala files. For some reason, the smart line join feature (Ctrl-Shift-J by default) seems to work well with Java files but not with Scala files.

Java code:

[image: Java code before Smart line join]

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

[image: Java code after Smart line join]

Scala code:

[image: Scala code before smart line join]

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

[image: Scala code after smart line join]

Am I missing some properties that I need to enable just to make this work for Scala files in the same project? I don't remember having to set any properties for this to work for Java code.